# system() returns bad exit code

Tags: perl

I am using `system` to call an external application and I need to interpret its exit code.

I know that `system` returns the exit code from the command multiplied by 256, but when in `foo.bat` I write `exit 256` the result is zero.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return code is a single-byte value from zero to 255.

The most reliable way to check the status of a `system` call is to examine `$?`. It's documented in [`perldoc perlfunc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) like this

```
if ($? == -1) {
    print "failed to execute: $!\n";
}
elsif ($? & 127) {
    printf "child died with signal %d, %s coredump\n",
        ($? & 127),  ($? & 128) ? 'with' : 'without';
}
else {
    printf "child exited with value %d\n", $? >> 8;
}
```

Comment: So I'm just unlucky if I have to deal with an 256? Is there something I can do?

Comment: @JohnDoe: Do you really have more than 255 different program statuses to report?

Comment: No, but maybe one day one developer who is not aware of this, makes this mistake and I don't want to leave this situation unhandled.

Comment: @JohnDoe you have 8 bits for a return code. You're trying to stuff `256` into it. It doesn't fit.

Comment: @JohnDoe: With all respect, a developer who doesn't know that a status code is restricted to an eight-bit value will have all sorts of other problems. If you must then add a comment to your code.

Comment: @Tanktalus, Exit codes are 32-bit long in Windows. exit 256 is perfectly valid, and it fits no problem (since there's no requirement for `$?` to be limited to 16 bits).

Answer (score 5):

Windows uses 32-bit exit codes, so `exit 256` is perfectly valid.

```
>cmd /c exit 256

>echo %ERRORLEVEL%
256
```

However, Perl only keeps the least significant 8 bits.

```
>perl -e"system 'exit 256'; CORE::say $?>>8"
0

>perl -e"system 'exit 266'; CORE::say $?>>8"
10
```

This is a Perl defect for which there's no good reason. If you use [Win32::Process](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32::Process) instead of `system`, you can obtain the correct exit code.

```
>perl -MWin32::Process=NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,INFINITE -e"Win32::Process::Create(my $proc, $ENV{COMSPEC}, 'cmd /c exit 256', 0, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, '.') or die $^E; $proc->Wait(INFINITE); $proc->GetExitCode(my $exit_code); CORE::say $exit_code;"
256
```

Comment: I just tried with `C` (gcc, Ubuntu), and `int main(void) {return 266;}` also gave 10. _<anecdote>But I remember we had a script at work that processed XML documents and the script's returncode indiciated the erroneous line number (if any). The script was reliable for input with <= 65536 lines, so I guess it depends on the environment whether 8 or 16 bits are ok for a returncode.</anecdote>_

Comment: @PerlDuck, No, it's not related to the environment. The environment always provides a `DWORD`. It's the wrappers you use (e.g. `system`) that may have limits.

Answer (score -1):

All the possibilities of failure can be obtained by examining `$?`.

```perl
$exit_val    = $? >> 8;
$signal      = $? & 127;
$dumped_core = $? & 128;`
```

To quote from [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Error-Variables) :

> - $CHILD_ERROR
> - $?
>
>   The status returned by the last pipe close, backtick (``) command, successful call to `wait()` or `waitpid()`, or from the `system()` operator. This is just the 16-bit status word returned by the traditional Unix `wait()` system call (or else is made up to look like it). Thus, the exit value of the subprocess is really (`$? >> 8` ), and `$? & 127` gives which signal, if any, the process died from, and `$? & 128` reports whether there was a core dump.

Comment: @Borodin Thanks for the edits. I am new to stackoverflow. I will be more careful in the future.